# How to tell weblogic that some JARs are located in fixed positions?

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, shared-libraries

I have a weblogic application (EAR) that references a Java EE library deployed on the same server. (referenced in the web-application.xml)

The Java EE library is targeted correctly to the weblogic server with my application.

The Java EE library points to a JAR (javaEElib.jar) file that is predeployed on the system in a specific path location and "javaEElib.jar" references in it's Manifest more JARs that are pre-deployed on the system in fixed locations. **The reference in the Manifest is relative (../../libs/someOtherJar.jar).**

My problem is that when i deploy my application it takes the referenced Java EE library JAR "javaEElib.jar" and puts it in its stage directory but in runtime it can't find the relative JARs (someOtherJar.jar) because those are not copied to the stage.

Is there some way to tell weblogic that "javaEElib.jar" is located in a fixed path on the system instead of copying it to the stage (so that it can find the relative sub jars) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy your javaEElib.jar as a library deployment in WebLogic as per [Creating Shared Java EE Libraries and Optional Packages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13706/libraries.htm#WLPRG327).

It then knows that it must be distributed correctly to each node in your cluster.

Comment: It was interesting to read about "optional packages" but it didn't solve my problem. I found a solution in the end with help of a friend.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Found the answer !
My problem was that I deployed the Java EE library wrongly (javaEElib.jar).
I deployed it normally where as I should have deployed it without staging.

When you deploy a Java EE library without staging it will not copy it into the staging are of any EAR/WAR you deploy that uses it.

To deploy a java EE library without staging, using admin web console for example, you do the following:
1. go to deployments screen
2. lock
3. click install
4. choose your jar
5. click "next", mark your server/cluster, click "next", go down to the bottom and mark the "I will make the deployment accessible from the following location" radio button and make sure the location written points to the fixed location disk.
6. click finish + "activate changes"